# Displaying owner's email address and name in textview

Tags: android, textview

This is my code for accounts manager. I want to Display owner's name and email address in textview

```
final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
if (accounts[0].name != null) {
    accountName = accounts[0].name;
    String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " = ?";
    ArrayList<String> what = new ArrayList<String>();
    what.add(accountName);
    txt2.setText(accountName);
    Log.v("Got account", "Account " + accountName);
}
```

It is displaying email address of owner/user. How can I get the profile/full/first name of user/owner?
A lot of questions like this have already asked on this web. But nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is he where statement for ?

```
String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " = ?";
```

Have a look at the Profile API :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html

This only works if user has configured the profile.

If you need the profile from server you can use directory search - Google and Exchange accounts support this.
You can query the directory with the email address that you have already managed to obtain and retrieve full data.